# Android new activity result API

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I want to use the new activity result API. I have this one in my Activity.

```
val openPostActivity = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            //Do something with the result
        }
```

and call it to get open a new intent. What i want to know is if there is any way for a child fragment of this activity to get the result as well?

Comment: I think you'll have to get the fragment via fragment manager, then call a method on the child fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a interface and implement it in the Fragment, it will help us to pass data from activity to fragment after we received data in activity.

```
interface SetDetailHandler {
    fun setDetails(detail: String)
}
```

Then in activity, find the fragment and send the data using the interface method.

```
 supportFragmentManager.fragments.firstOrNull().let { fragment ->
                val setDetailHandler = fragment as? SetDetailHandler
                setDetailHandler?.setDetails("Hello")
            }
```